# Guy becomes immortal after kissing a girl

Tags: kurozuka

I am looking for the name of a certain anime I saw when I was younger. It was about a guy who was fleeing into the mountains for some reason. In these mountains he found a woman. After kissing her he found out that he became immortal and lived for thousands of years. I also remember that the moment they kissed he would feel inhuman pain for 3 consecutive days.

**Edit:** 
I can't properly remember the art style or the music used. I am sure it was a series around 12 episodes. I watched it subbed and don't believe there was any dubbed version (I don't really watch those so didn't pay attention to that). I believe it was a Madhouse production but I can't tell that for sure. The moment I started watching it had just about ended and I believe the end was a bit of a vampire-like story or at least hinted at a vampire-like plot.

I remembered a bit more about the plot: it was set in medieval times between 1200 and 1400, I think. But halfway through the plot, he loses consciousness and stays so for 1000 years and ends up in a post-apocalyptic Japan where he starts to search for his beloved (the one who kissed and made him immortal). Also it was not 2007 when I watched it but the end of 2008. I read the manga in 2007.

Comment: When were you younger?

Comment: @coleopterist i saw it end 2007 so 6 years back

Comment: Did the animation look new to you or old-school? Do you remember if it was subbed or dubbed? Was it a movie or a series? Please add as many details as you can to your question.

Comment: @coleopterist Added more details in the question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds somewhat similar to [Kurozuka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurozuka).

> The series begins in 12th century Japan and centers on Kuro, a character based loosely on the legendary Japanese swordsman Minamoto no Yoshitsune. Kuro and his servant, Benkei, meet a beautiful and mysterious woman named Kuromitsu while on the run from Kuro's elder brother, who seeks his life. Kuromitsu and Kuro fall in love, but he soon discovers that she harbors a terrible secret: she is a vampiric immortal. Following an attack by his pursuers, Kuro is badly injured and must imbibe Kuromitsu's blood to save his own life. Kuro is then betrayed and attacked by Benkei, who has been subverted by a shadowy organization called the Red Army, and Kuro's head is severed, which interferes with his transformation into a fully immortal being. 
>   Kuro loses consciousness and wakes up centuries later in a post-apocalyptic, dystopian Japan. The surviving citizens have fallen under constant oppression by the Red Army, and Kuro is quickly found and recruited by an underground revolutionary movement called Haniwa. The remaining episodes follow Kuro's fight with the Red Army and its host of elite warriors, who have been enhanced by samples of Kuromitsu's blood, and his quest to find his inexplicably lost love.

The anime is also by Madhouse from 2008.

Comment: You just made a bullseye Thats it :3!!!  ( added my mistake  i read the manga in 2007  anime end 2008)

Answer (score 3):

[Princess Resurrection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Resurrection) (怪物王女 Kaibutsu Ōjo?, lit. Monster Princess) is a Japanese horror comedy manga by Yasunori Mitsunaga.

> Hiro Hiyorimi is a boy who has just moved to the Sasanaki City to meet his sister. While walking down the sidewalk, he is suddenly hit by a car (crushed by construction beams in the anime). On the verge of death, he is seen by a young woman clad in gothic clothes. **She then resurrects him, leaving him alive in the hospital morgue.** He wakes up confused over what happened, only to encounter the woman again as she eliminates some wolf creatures. She addresses Hiro as "her servant" and introduces herself as "Hime" (Japanese for Princess) and explains that she is a member of the royal family of the Monster Realm.

No mountains apparently. But the rest of the plot appears to share the same ballpark. The time-frame is also a fit.

The manga is still ongoing.

Comment: Doesent seem to be the one, Does like one i will watch later on though. It was A older style, there were no cars yet. useing blades and stuff like that  although this did make me remmeber more ill update my question with more details

Comment: @Dimitrimx I see :( The Wiki also mentions the vampires that you've mentioned. Please add blades and 2007 to your question.

Comment: added all information i just remmemberd it was bit of dark blackish anime :/

Comment: @Dimitrimx Well done :)

Answer (score 0):

"A Dark Rabbit Has Seven Lives" or the Japanese name "Itsuka Tenma No Kuro Usagi".

> Taito has been really sleepy lately, and keeps dreaming of a female vampire who says she has given him her “poison.” Sometimes he even thinks he hears her voice when he’s awake. But after surviving an accident that should have killed him, Taito’s world changes drastically and he realizes that his dreams are more real than he thought. its a cool anime

Comment: You know this anime you mentioned, and kurozuka are so alike